# Multiple module projects with intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have 2 projects, ProjectA and ProjectB.
ProjectB is a standalone project and ProjectA is dependent on ProjectB.
Of course the pom in ProjectA has the dependency of ProjectB as follow:

```
 <overlays>
        <overlay>
            <groupId>ProjectB</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectBwar</artifactId>
        </overlay>
    </overlays>
```

...

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectB</groupId>
                <artifactId>ProjectBwar</artifactId>
                <version>ProjectBVersion</version>
                <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

When working with only ProjectA, everything is fine.  Once I import module of ProjectB into the same project, Intellij is importing it fine but it's still using the maven dependency on the build and I'm unable to do any testing on changes done in ProjectB.  Is there a way to tell Intellij to not use the maven dependency and instead use the module I have imported?
I've tried going into the project structure, but I'm unsure of where to go and what to change.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You'll likely want to specify the dependent module in the `<modules>` tag shown in [this example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html) instead of listing it as a dependency, if it's managed and used in the same project as your parent. Since you specify it's a standalone project that you're dependent on, then you don't use it by importing the module, you `install` project A's pom and artifact and you resolve it from your local maven repo in project B.

Comment: @RyanJ, The pom has all the relevant modules for the project in the parent-pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your library module as a project dependency, and any changes to your library will be visible in your project immediately. Assuming you have both your project and library modules within your IntelliJ project, go to:

`File > Project Structure > Modules > select your project module > Dependencies > + > Module Dependency > select your library module`

Comment: When listed as an **overlay** as long as the pom versions match Intellij picks it up properly automatically.  When listed as **dependency** this is the proper approach.  As I ran into the issue again today.
Thanks!